# Player not detecting layermask

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to implement a simple collision detection for my player but it is not detecting the layer mask as my Player comes into contact with it. I have a move point that moves slightly ahead of the player, and if it comes in contact with the StopMovement layermask then it should NOT move any further. Unfortunately, the layer is never detected and therefore the player just moves right through the object.

Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    private float moveHorizontal;
    private float moveVertical;

    public Transform movePoint;

    public LayerMask whatStopsMovement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        movePoint.parent = null;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        // stops the movePoint from going too far
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) == 0f)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) == 1f) // makes it so we can check if 1f OR -1f without == 1f || -1f
            {
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0f, 0f), 0.2f, whatStopsMovement))
                {
                    Debug.Log("No collision");
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0f);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Collision");
                }
            }

            else if (Mathf.Abs(moveVertical) == 1f) // makes it so we can check if 1f OR -1f without == 1f || -1f
            {
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(moveVertical, 0f, 0f), 0.4f, whatStopsMovement))
                {
                    Debug.Log("No collision");
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(0f, moveVertical);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Collision");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Physics2D.OverlapCircle` detects `Collider2D` components.

Your square obstacle does not have a `Collider2D` that we can see, so it will be invisible to physics methods.

Comment: Ahhh such a silly mistake! Thank you for pointing it out. I feel so embarrassed haha